# jshell error: missing return statement when setting boolean method

Tags: java

I'm trying to run this program in jshell but it keeps giving me the error

missing return statement.

I've also tried by just typing in straight to the terminal(I'm using mac terminal) but it still gives the same error.

```
boolean isit5(int five){
  if (five == 5){
  reuturn true;
  }
}

Error:
|  missing return statement

|  boolean is5(int five){
                        ^
```

void method works for me but somehow boolean methods gives me the error.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if five is not 5 then what is returned?

Comment: @ScaryWombat this is just a very very simple code to show what I'm trying to do, I just couldn't set boolean method in jshell and return anything. Even if I have else if or else.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm a beginner, don't judge my code too much. I thought the code is correct when I put this up. Can you explain how to use boolean method in jshell and return true or false?

Comment: See below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jshell> boolean isit5(int five){
   ...> if (five == 5) return true;
   ...> return false;
   ...> }
|  created method isit5(int)

jshell> isit5 (10);
$2 ==> false

jshell>
```

Comment: I didn't know I have to put return on the same line as the if. Thank you so much.

Comment: Does not need to be on the same line.

Comment: That's what the answer's code mean: `if (five == 5) {return true;} return false;` and this is better: `if (five == 5) {return true;} else {return false;}`